# Android login page gives 408 error but confirm page exist

Tags: java, android

I am trying out a login page on adroid and keep getting error 408 where I have confirm my page exist on the server. Following are my codes.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener   {

    Button ok,back,exit;
     TextView result;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            // Login button clicked
            ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            ok.setOnClickListener(this);

           // result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);
            //ok.setOnClickListener(loginOnClickListener);  
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
              if(view == ok){
                  EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                    String username = uname.getText().toString();

                    EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
                    String password = pword.getText().toString();
                    Log.w("SENCIDE",username );
                    Log.w("SENCIDE",password );
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(MainActivity.this, progressDialog);
                    loginTask.execute(username,password);
              }
            }
        /*protected OnClickListener loginOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

            }
        };*/

        public void showLoginError(int result)
        {

            Log.w("SENCIDE",Integer.toString(result) );
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        // do some stuff after user logs in
        public void login(int id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK LOGGED IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

**LoginTask.java**

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private MainActivity activity;
private int id = -1;

public LoginTask(MainActivity activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{
    String result = "";
    int responseCode = 0;
    try 
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(" http://*****/***/login.php");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", arg0[0]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", arg0[1]));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        int executeCount = 0;
        HttpResponse response;
        do
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in.. ("+(executeCount+1)+"/5)");
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            executeCount++;
            response = client.execute(httppost);
            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                        
            // If you want to see the response code, you can Log it
            // out here by calling:
            // Log.d("256 Design", "statusCode: " + responseCode)
        } while (executeCount < 5 && responseCode == 408);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result = line.trim();
        }
        id = Integer.parseInt(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        responseCode = 408;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer headerCode)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if(headerCode == 202)
        activity.login(id);
    else{
        activity.showLoginError(headerCode);
    }
}
```

Following are my AndoirdManifest.xml where I have given the Internet permission.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.guard1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I captured some error in my logcat.

```
10-06 01:11:54.969: W/System.err(1801): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-06 01:11:54.999: W/System.err(1801):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
10-06 01:11:54.999: W/System.err(1801):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
10-06 01:11:54.999: W/System.err(1801):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
10-06 01:11:54.999: W/System.err(1801):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10935)
10-06 01:11:54.999: W/System.err(1801):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10890)
10-06 01:11:55.099: W/System.err(1801):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6587)
10-06 01:11:55.099: W/System.err(1801):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
10-06 01:11:55.109: W/System.err(1801):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
10-06 01:11:55.189: W/System.err(1801):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
10-06 01:11:55.189: W/System.err(1801):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(ProgressDialog.java:316)
10-06 01:11:55.189: W/System.err(1801):     at com.example.guard1.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:56)
10-06 01:11:55.199: W/System.err(1801):     at com.example.guard1.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:1)
10-06 01:11:55.229: W/System.err(1801):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-06 01:11:55.229: W/System.err(1801):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-06 01:11:55.239: W/System.err(1801):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-06 01:11:55.239: W/System.err(1801):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-06 01:11:55.239: W/System.err(1801):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-06 01:11:55.249: W/System.err(1801):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: try the toast inside a runOnUiThread

Comment: Which function should I toast in you mean doInBackground?

Comment: I think Your error is not because of 408,its because of UI thread,So try the activity.login(id) inside a runOnUiThread.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit lost here where to put this  activity.login(id)  ? I am very new so what is the UI thread?

Comment: Me also new to android, check my answer it may help you, its a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in both toast and any other UI changes.

```
public void login(int id)
        {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK LOGGED IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

        }
```

Comment: I tried and saw this in my logcat 10-06 02:29:01.919: I/Choreographer(1956): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-06 02:29:02.279: I/Choreographer(1956): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
The final result still pointing to the error function

Comment: Ok I did the changes you gave and added this toast while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
   {
    result = line.trim();
    Log.w("SENCIDE RSULT",result );
   } Confirm that it prints the right results.So now is the passing issue I guess rite

Comment: I also notice the response code is actually 200 not 202

Comment: I am very confuse when you say UI related codes. So just to share with you I just did this changes now if(headerCode == 200){
         
                         activity.login(id);
     }      and it works perfectly fine. So the issue was with the response code. There is no need to run the runOnUIThread